# In Gmail, I want all labels to be visible, I don't want to have to click "More" every time. Possible?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

In Gmail, I want to be able to see all labels on the left, without scrolling to the bottom of the list and clicking `More`.  Mainly because the `More` label is usually covered up by a popup or a notification, and it's just in an inconvenient place way down there at the bottom left, and it's just an unnecessary extra click.

For example, I quite often want to navigate to `All Mail` and `Trash` and it's unnecessarily painful being under the `More` drop-down.

Is there a setting for this - to have all labels showing all the time, or is there some other way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your labels' visibility under `Settings` as shown in the image bellow.

[image: show Gmail labels]

Comment: Wow. I'm actually embarrassed to say I didn't think to look there.  Cheers!!